# Нажатие кнопки в Selenium - Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

Есть код на странице кнопок:

```html
<td colspan="5">
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl00','')" style="color:#D95221;">...</a>
&nbsp;
<span style="color:Black;">11</span>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl02','')" style="color:#D95221;">12</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl03','')" style="color:#D95221;">13</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl04','')" style="color:#D95221;">14</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl05','')" style="color:#D95221;">15</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl06','')" style="color:#D95221;">16</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl07','')" style="color:#D95221;">17</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl08','')" style="color:#D95221;">18</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl09','')" style="color:#D95221;">19</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl10','')" style="color:#D95221;">20</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl11','')" style="color:#D95221;">...</a>
</td>
```

Видим: есть две клавиши с текстом "...", как нажать именно вторую клавишу? Какие способы можно применить? По-моему, локаторы мне не помогут в этом случае.

Comment: Если программно нажать, то, как вариант, повешать ID на элемент для его нахождения в рунтайме.

Comment: Понял, а с помощью чего это делается?

Comment: HTML: <a id="someId" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$BrandsDG$ctl14$ctl11','')" style="color:#D95221;">...</a> JS: document.getElementById('someId').click();

Comment: Хорошо, но как именно повесить в реальном времени этот ID к нужной кнопки?

Comment: Больше ничего добавить не могу, т.к. с Selenium не знаком. Я вам только подсказал возможен путь решения.

Comment: Если точно известно, что нужно нажать именно на второе троеточие, то можно использовать такой xpath `//td/a[text()="..."][2]`